# Where can I find the total enthalpy and heat of dissolution in water of a given components?

Tags: enthalpy, heat

I don't really have a background in chemistry but I'm actually studying in aerospace engineering, sorry if this question may seem trivial.

I am interested in the decomposition process of the hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$) and I need to find the total enthalpies of $\ce{H2O2}$, $\ce{H2O (l)}$, $\ce{H2O (g)}$ and $\ce{O2 (g)}$ and the heat of dissolution ($\Delta H_{\text{dis}}$)of $\ce{H2O2}$ in water, as a function of the solution concentration of $\ce{H2O2}$.

Firstly, I tried to find the values of the total enthalpies, but I couldn't find them. However, I found a lot of values about the $\Delta H^0$ and $h^o_f$. I can't understand if I can retrieve the value of $H$ with the $\Delta H^0$ and/or $h^o_f$.

Secondly, I can't find a good answer to another question. Does the $H$ is a function of the pressure or not? If so, how can I find the value of $H$ at a given pressure and a given temperature?

Comment: See Smith and Van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics or Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics to get the heat of reaction from heats of formation, and to get the effect of pressure on enthalpy.

Answer (score -1):

It's very unlikely you actually need the enthalpy.  Like energy (of which it is a variation), absolute enthalpy is almost unmeasureable, normally one deals only in enthalpy *changes*.  In your case I would hazard a guess that you're  interested in things like dH_rxn, the heat of reaction for the decomposition of H2O2.  You can readily calculate this from the dH0 of the components.  The latter are called the "standard heats of formation" and they are combined with "Hess's Law."  Googling either of those terms should lead you to explanations of how the data you can find can be combined into the data you want. How exactly you do it will depend on what quantity you want, and the thermodynamic conditions (e.g. T and p) under which you want it, and the accuracy you need.

Yes, H is generally a function of pressure and temperature.  The starting search term there would probably be "derivatives of the enthalpy" because you would generally calculate H at one (T,p) from H0 at some other (T0,po). You'll find the derivatives can be related to material properties like the heat capacity, compressibility, and coefficient of thermal expansion.  For changes over significant temperature ranges these can be integrated, provided they are known as functions of temperature, or you are willing to use approximate models (like the ideal gas model) that have formulae.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually find the heat of reaction for the decomposition of H2O2, but I do not understand how to relate this value to the temperature of the products. That's why I tried to use another technique to find this value. This technique requires the total enthlapies.

Comment: If you mean, relate dH at one temperature to dH at another, then start with derivatives of the enthalpy.  If you mean how a release of a certain amount of heat will change the temperature of something, including the reactants, then what you need is the heat capacity.